# i3 command to toggle picom that greps ps for "picom" works when it should fail, as "picom" is in the command and shows up in "ps" output

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, ps, i3

I have this line in my i3 config:

```bash
bindsym $Super+Shift+F10 exec --no-startup-id ps aux | grep -q '[p]icom' && killall picom || picom
```

It runs a shell command (everything after --no-startup-id is the shell command) when pressing a keybind. The shell command successfully lets me toggle compositing using picom on my desktop. It runs a command that gets a list of all processes with ps and search through it for "picom" using grep. If grep finds something, it returns true and then killall will kill all picom running. If grep finds nothing, it will start picom.

But here is the problem, the command has "picom" in it, twice even, so grep should always see it and return true, and therefore, the command should always run `killall picom`, right?

To see if that was the case, I modified the command to add tee to log the output of ps in a file called log1:

```bash
bindsym $Super+Shift+F10 exec --no-startup-id ps aux | tee log1 | grep -q '[p]icom' && killall picom || picom
```

Output of `cat log1 | grep picom` when no picom is running after using the i3 keybinding above:

```
ordici   19951  0.0  0.0   3192  2040 ?        Ss   17:24   0:00 /bin/sh -c ps aux | tee log1 | grep -q '[p]icom' && killall picom || picom
```

So I am right, the output of ps has picom in it even when picom is not running. So how come the command works flawlessly?

Even more weird is that, when the command is run from the terminal instead of the i3 keybind and that picom is not running, the log of ps does not have my command in it. Yet the command still works, as I expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

By writing the question, I realized why it works. I guess I will post it anyway, so I won't have written this for nothing.

`grep picom` dose always return true in my scenario, as I expected it did. So, it always runs `killall picom`. It is as if the command is the following (which is the command I will be using from now on):

```bash
killall picom || picom
```

The reason it works is that `killall` has an exit value too! When `killall` does not find any process named "picom" to kill, it returns a non-zero exit value. This in turns triggers the picom to run as the command right before it failed!

So both `grep` or `killall` failing can trigger `picom` to run in my original command. This is a difference between if statements and logical operators like "&& ||". Logical operators make it so more than one command in the chain of AND Operator (`&&`) failing will trigger the OR Operator (`||`).

I transformed the original command into an if statement as a test:

```bash
if ps aux | grep -q '[p]icom'; then
    killall picom
else
    picom
fi
```

And the command fails to toggle `picom` as expected, as the only deciding factor if `killall` or `picom` is executed is the return value of `grep`, and `grep` always return true in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother with `ps` and `grep`-ing for `picom` if `killall` will just silently fail if it's not running? It seems like you could just do:

```
killall picom || picom
```

As for the multiple conditional tests on command results (exit statuses), this:

```
grep -q '[p]icom' && { killall picom; true; } || picom
```

is what you'd need to do that without using an if-else since, as you've now discovered `a && b || c` is not a [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_conditional_operator), i.e. it does not mean:

```
if a; then
    b
else
    c
fi
```

it instead means (`es` = exit status):

```
a; es=$?
if (( es == 0 )); then
    b; es=$?
fi
if (( es != 0 )); then
    c; es=$?
fi
(exit $es)
```

See [bash-if-statement-versus-conditional-execution-logic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77629178/1745001) for a related answer that might help make the above clearer.